# AJAX form data not sending from PHP included pages

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

I am building a sign up form, and want to include it into a div on the main page. The main page also includes a 'log in' form.

Both forms are included on the page using php include commands in the appropriate div i.e:

```
<?php include_once("login.php")?>    
<?php include_once("signup.php")?>
```

Now when I use ajax on the second form i.e. the signup.php form, it sends back information from the fields in the first form. It doesn't help that they are both email and password fields.

Does anyone know how I can isolate the information from each form so i can send the data from each form separately? Below is all the relevant code for the forms and the Javascript.

Here is the code for the first form(login.php):

```
  <form name="loginform" id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input style="margin-bottom:5px;" id="email" type="text" class="searchbox" onblur="checkusername()" maxlength="35" value="Email">
    <span id="emailstatus"></span>
    <input id="password" class="searchbox" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')"  maxlength="88" value="Password">
    <p><a href="#" id="loginbtn" onclick="login()">Log In / <a href="#" onclick="forgotpass()">Forgot Password</a></p>
    <span id="status"></span>
  </form>
```

and the ajax for it:

```
function login(){
//isolate the variables from the form
var p = _("password").value;
var e = _("email").value;
var status = _("status");
if(e != "Email" && p != "Password"){
    _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
    status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';

//start the Ajax Request

    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                status.innerHTML = 'There was a problem. Please check your email and password and try again. ';
                _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
            }  else {
                window.location = "user.php?id="+ajax.responseText; 

            }
        }
    }

//data being sent by the ajax call

    ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
} else {
    status.innerHTML = "You're missing something..";
}
}

function emptyElement(x){
//The _(x) function is a shortcut for getElementById
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}

//This jQuery used to pre populate the email and password fields with "email" and "password"
$('input .seachbox').each(function(){
    $(this)
    .data('default', $(this).val())
    .focus(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('default')||''){
        $(this).val() = ''
        }
    })
    .blur(function(){
    var default_val = $(this).data('default');
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).val($(this).data('default'))
    }
    }); 
});
```

and the second form(signup.php):

```
     <form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="emails" type="text" class="searchbox" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" class="searchbox" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" class="searchbox" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
      </form>           
<br> <a href="#" alt="Signup" onclick="signup()">Create Account</a><p>
<div class="statuserror"><span id="status" >This is a permanent error</span></div>
    </div>
```

and the ajax for it:

```
function signup(){
var e = _("email").value;
var p1 = _("pass1").value;
var p2 = _("pass2").value;
var status = _("status");
if( e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == ""){
    status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
} else if(p1 != p2){
    status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
} else {
    status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            if(ajax.responseText != "OK"){
                status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                _("p1").innerHTML = "Please check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p1);
}
```

[image: This is a screenshot with the Firebug output - the response from the POST should appear where the red text is on the page.]

EDIT - SOLUTION:- Have - after 3 days found a solution so stupid i had to share it. Basically I changed the id of the status div from "status" to "status1" and found that everything is working fine now. I think that it might be because on the login page I also have a div named status so the browser is unsure which div to put it in and just does nothing. This also explains why the signup.php page works when run alone in the browser but not when the login.php is included along with it in the main page.

Moral of the story - MAKE SURE YOUR IDS ARE ALL DIFFERENT!! 
Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: It could be just a "typo" in your ajax call. In the second JS code you have "var e = _("email").value;" when it is supposed to be "var e = _("emails").value;"

Comment: Thanks Daniel! That's been killing me for two days!

Comment: one other question - any ideas why the #status span in the second script may not show the ajaxesponseText when the script is included?

Comment: @Mobaz why dont you use a javascript library which will make your life much easy

Comment: @kishore - i've recently started using JQuery so just getting used to it, but you're right - the AJAX calls in JQuery are far simpler - thanks

Comment: @Mobaz, Are you trying to return JS and HTML in the Ajax call?... if so... not all browsers will execute (eval) that code. I would recommend you to return JSON and use that to update your UI programatically. jQuery will help you a lot with that!

Comment: @Daniel - i'm not actually returning anything other than either an 'OK' string from the php to say all the server side script has been completed or a error string e.g. "This email is already in the system". Once that's done then the ajax is to take over and show the response text if it is an error (i.e. != 'OK') else set the status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;

Comment: Strange thing is that it works when i run signup.php on the browser - just not when i load it into another page

Comment: OK... when you debug the script, in the line "status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;", What is value of "status"? (It is supposed to be the SPAN element)... If you have that page publicly hosted somewhere, I can look at it if you want.

Comment: Hi Daniel - unfortunately its not hosted - when i debug it as a standalone page it spits out the correct response from php i.e. when i put an email that's already in the db it says: "That email address is already in use in the system." etc

Comment: status is a span element that appears just under the form - originally it's empty and is used to house the responses

Comment: Yeah, your PHP code is correct, what I wanted to test is if the javascript variable "status" still have a valid reference to your SPAN when it gets to the line "status.innerHTML = ..."... try debugging it or add the line "console.log(status);" right before that line to see if it has a valid reference.... if it does... then I have no idea why it would not show the data.

Comment: get "<span id="status">"

Comment: Then it should work... sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: no worries - thanks for your help! its a massive pain

Comment: Are both files included in the same script? I would do something like this: ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&action=login"); (or action=signup) and, in your PHP, do something like: if ($_POST['action'] == "login") { /\* login here \*/ } elseif ($_POST['action'] == "signup") { /\* signup here \*/ } else { /\* bad request here \*/ }

Comment: Hi Alejandro - Thanks for your contribution but I found that the problem was coming as a result of two ID being the same (which I missed because I was loading one page into another) I'm sure this would also work.