# Javascript restrict() to filter input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have looked around and really haven't found anything in regards to this function and what I would like to do with it.

In a registration form I have the following :

```
<label>*Email
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" minlength="5" maxlength="40" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')"/>
</label>
```

In the javascript file I have input :

```
function restrict(elem){
            var tf = _(elem);
            var rx = new RegExp;
            if(elem === "email"){
                rx = /[' "]/gi;
            } else if(elem === "username"){
                rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
            }
            tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
        }
```

What I am trying to do is limit what is in this field and the username field to the restrictions mentioned above.

The error from the console is : TypeError: tf.value.replace is not a function.

Thank you for any tips anyone may have !

Comment: what is `_(elem)`? What library is that from? The standard jQuery prefix is `$`

Comment: I'm currently learning Java and jQuery - most of the time I fix my mistakes via the console and/or searching the web... 

Here I'm using an online registration form that's a couple years old. The original form used the following on the' function signup() { var u = _("username").value;' ....etc in order to set variables. I modified this to 'var username = document.getElementById("username").value;' in order for it to work. 

Therefore I'm not sure what language it was.. it just didn't look right and doesn't run... anymore at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message means that the function `String.replace` does not exist on `tf.value`. This is because `tf.value` isn't a string. To figure out what's going on, you can look to the jQuery documentation and see how they want you to [get](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val1) and [set](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) the value of an element.

Looking at those two links, you can see that the correct way to set and get the value of an element is like this:

```
// Set    
$(element).val("value");

// Get
$(element).val();
```

There's a few other issues with you code. First of all, jQuery normally uses a `$` as a prefix. Secondly jQuery uses [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) when finding elements, so you need to prefix any id with `#` in order to find an element by id. You code should look something like this in the end:

```
function restrict(elem){
  var tf = $('#' + elem);
  var rx = new RegExp();
  if(elem === "email"){
    rx = /[' "]/gi;
  } else if(elem === "username"){
    rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
  }
  tf.val(tf.val().replace(rx, ""));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bennett! 

What is the purpose of having the '#' alongside the elem, if I may ask - to help understand ?

Comment: It's an important part of CSS selectors. If an element has id=email then you'd get it by using "#email". If it has "class=email" then you'd find it by using ".email"

Comment: Oh got it so it adds the # to the elem in question! :) 

In regards to the use that I had found with the `_("username").value` an other person is using it in an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549951/ajax-form-data-not-sending-from-php-included-pages) so I'm confused about where that comes from... possibly just old an many examples with this format are at least 2-3 years old

Comment: Ah I see the problem! If you read through the code, there's a comment that says `_(x)` is a shortcut for `document.getElementById(x)` that they wrote themselves. That example you referenced doesn't use jQuery but just plain JavaScript.